# Set custom header text size for teasers

Tags: nodes

I've created a frontpage which uses a the 34/33/34 panel layout and linked different contents to it (another pages). By checking the code using Firebug i see that teasers on this front page inherited the H2 class settings for header text, so they appear with the same text size just as they appear in full content view.

I'd like to customize the size of the header texts of the teasers on the front page. Any suggestion welcomed!

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. If this is generic HTML / CSS question, it is off-topic here. Might be on-topic on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS to alter the size of your H2 elements on the home page.

Replace in this code XX by the desired font-size, and it will apply to all h2 elements but only on the home page (body.front)

```
body.front h2 {
  font-size:XXpx;
}
```

Otherwise, learn CSS to understand how to select your specific elements.